# Retrofit put method call update the item but give 400 response code in error in android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit to update some information. The information is updated in the database. But i am getting 400 error code in response. At the same time the API works perfectly in postman.
I have double-checked that I'm sending the required headers and the API token which updated on every login. But I'm get 400 error still, while the information is updated.

this is [image: the response of the API]

Comment: Add your Retrofit builder class where you are adding token using intereptor

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 401 as a status code that means unauthorized token you are passing or something wrong with the auth token

- Check auth token you are passing is correct or not or you are passing it or not.
- If you are not passing auth token in the api header then please pass it will resolve your error

Comment: i have passed the api token both dynamically and static and i have also checked the api token if it is expired or not but still the same error it even show in the picture i have passed the auth token and with the same token i am running the postman it work..

Comment: don't pass bearer only pass token. or just add your class where you are passing token on question

Answer (score 0):

```
this is api module class     

  var token = ""
            if (prefs.contains(Constants.TOKEN_VALUE)) {
                prefs.read(Constants.TOKEN_VALUE)?.let {
                    token = it
                }
            }
    
            val httpInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            httpInterceptor.level = httpLoggingLevel
    
            val okHttp = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(httpInterceptor).addInterceptor { chain ->
                        val requestBuilder = chain.request().newBuilder()
                        requestBuilder.addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                        requestBuilder.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                        requestBuilder.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    
                        if (token.isNotEmpty() && Constants.apitokenheader==0) {
                            requestBuilder.addHeader("Authorization", token)
                            Log.d("apitoken", "providesBaseApiService: $token")
                        }
                        chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build())
                    }
                    .addInterceptor { chain ->
                        val request = chain.request()
                        val response = chain.proceed(request)
                        when(response.code()){
                            200, 201 -> response
                            204 -> response.newBuilder().code(200).body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.get("application/json"), "1")).build()
                            else -> {
                                try {
                                    response.body()?.byteStream()?.readBytes()?.toString(Charset.defaultCharset())?.let {
                                        val obj = JSONObject(it)
                                        val opt = obj.optString("message", "An error occurred, Please try again.")
                                        Log.v("error message", opt)
                                        Log.v("error message1", request.url().toString())
                                        Log.v("error message2", response.code().toString())
    
                                        val link = request.url().uri().toString()
                                        val sub : String = link.substringAfterLast("v1")
                                        Log.v("DripInventory", sub)
                                        Log.v("DripInventory", link.indexOf("v1").let { if (it == -1) null else link.substring(it + 1) })
    //                                    link.indexOf("v1").let { if (it == -1) null else link.substring(it + 1) }
    
                                        //response.newBuilder().code(422).message(opt).build()
                                        response.newBuilder().code(response.code().toInt())
                                                .message("Please contact Drip Inventory." +
                                                        "\n " +
                                                        "\nResponse Code: ${response.code()}" +
                                                        "\n " +
                                                        "\nApi Call: $sub")
                                                .build()
    
                                    }
                                }catch (e: Exception){
                                    response
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        /*if (response.code() == 204) {
                            response.newBuilder().code(200).body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.get("application/json"), "1")).build()
                        } else {
                            response
                        }*/
                    }
                    .hostnameVerifier{hostname, session ->
                        if (hostname == "dripinventory.com") return@hostnameVerifier true
                        if (hostname == "invalid.demo.dripinventory.com") return@hostnameVerifier true
                        Log.v("hostname", hostname)
                        true
                    }
                    .build()
    
            val gson = GsonBuilder()
                    // Serializers
                    .registerTypeAdapter(CreateAssetRequest::class.java, CreateAssetRequestSerializer())
                    .registerTypeAdapter(UpdateAssetRequest::class.java, UpdateAssetRequestSerializer())
                    // Deserializers
                    .registerTypeAdapter(AssetRaw::class.java, AssetRawDeserializer())
                    .create()
    
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .client(okHttp)
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build()
    
            return retrofit.create(CcAssetManagerApi::class.java)
```